# How to iterate over two tables simultaneously

Tags: lua

I am something on a newbie when it comes to Lua and am having trouble trying to establish just how I iterate over two tables simultaneously.  The code below demonstrates what I am trying to do.  A few explanations

**I have two strings**

1. **slug** - a string bearing the form `a/b/c`
2. **holds** - another string that has the same form, say `x/y/z`

**What I do**

3. Break up the two strings on the / character and get two tables.
4. Iterate over the `slug` table and place each of its parts in another table, `slugs`.
5. Whilst doing so if an element in `slug` contains a hyphen `slugs` gets not one entry but two. Thus if slug is `hello/world/stackoverflow` would produce a `slugs` table with three elements: hello, world and stackoverflow
6. However, `hello/world/stack-overflow` would produce a table with **FOUR** elements: hello, world, stack and overflow.

**The problem**

I now output another table, `parts` which is indexed on the entries in the original `hold` table. With no hyphen driven breakup there is a one-to-one correspondence and `parts` contains

```
{a:hello,b:world,c:stackoverflow}
```

However, with a hyphen, `hello\world\stack-overflow` `parts` contains

```
{a:hello,b:world,c:stack}
```

*overflow* never makes it.  I suspect that there might be  away to avoid this by iterating over the two tables simultaneously.  However, I am unable to understand how/if this can be done. I tried to follow the notes in [this tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/IteratorsTutorial)  but made little headway.

In an ideal world what I would be able to do is to modify the `hold` table on-the-fly so it contains `{a,b,c0,c1}` when a hyphen is detected at the *c* position in its partner, `slug`, table.

With this alteration in place the `parts` table that is output would now contain

```
{a:hello,b:world,c0:stack,c1:overflow}
```

I should mention that I am using Lua 5.1 with no option to upgrade to a more recent version.

```
function explode(div,str)
 if (div=='') then return false end
 local pos,arr = 0,{};
 local part = "";
 for st,sp in function() return string.find(str,div,pos,true) end do
  part = string.sub(str,pos,st-1);
  if ((0 < string.len(part)) and ("rest" ~= part)) then
   table.insert(arr,part);
  end;
  pos = sp + 1
 end
 table.insert(arr,string.sub(str,pos))
 return arr
end;

function resolveParts(slug,holds)
 local parts,slugs = {},{};

 for i,s in pairs(slug) do
  if (string.find(s,'%-')) then
     s = explode('-',s);
     table.insert(slugs,s[1]);
     table.insert(slugs,s[2]);
  else
     table.insert(slugs,s);
    end;
end;

--slugs has **FOUR** elements since over-flow got broken up into two
for i,hold in pairs(holds) do
 parts[hold] = slugs[i];
end;
--iterating on the "old" holds table will result in parts missing one entry
```

end;

```
local slug = explode('/',"hello/stack/over-flow");
local holds = explode("/","a/b/c");
--Both slug & hold are tables containing 3 elements
local parts = resolveParts(slug,holds);
```

Comment: @YuHao - I have edited my question to better explain what the desired outcome should be.

Comment: Is the format of the intermediate `slugs` a requirement? If not I would suggest that instead of replacing the string `over-flow` with two strings that you replace it with a table of strings so you get `slugs={"hello", "stack", {"over", "flow"}}` which then allows you to iterate on those sub-tables in `resolveParts` to get the common prefixing you desire.

Comment: @EtanReisner - what you suggest may well be the solution.  There is no absolute requirement that `slugs` contain the final number  of elements - hyphen parsed when required.  I suppose I could test each element of `slugs` and when they are found to be a table output two values, `c0` and `c1` in my example. I am going to lave this question open for a while longer. However, suggest what you did as an answer and I will at the very least vote it up.

Comment: Yes, the idea was that your `resolveParts` loop would test the type of value in `slugs` and when it was a string act as normal but when it was a table it would add another loop and a counter so as to output `c# = subtab[i]` fields for as many as exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @EtanReisner's  suggestion, keep the hyphenated values in a table. This way, you will avoid problems with associating keys with one another, such as c0, c1, by making the relationship explicit in the data structure. Encoding anything in strings is asking for trouble later on when you have to use that encoded relationship (messy messy code) or when it breaks with different inputs (e.g, `hold='c/c5/a/a3'`)

```
 function split(str, sep)
   local parts = {} 
   for m in str:gmatch('[^'..sep..']+') do
     parts[#parts + 1] = m
   end
   return parts
end

function join(ks, vs)
  local t = {}
  for i, k in pairs(ks) do
     t[k] = vs[i]
  end
  return t
end

slugs = split('hello/stack/over-flow', '/')
holds = split('a/b/c', '/')
parts = join(holds, slugs)

-- check for hyphens and split again
for k, v in pairs(parts) do
   if v:find'-' then
     parts[k] = split(v, '-')
   end
end

-- check for table or string when using parts
for k, v in pairs(parts) do
   if type(v) == "table" then
      for i, vi in ipairs(v) do
         print(k..i, vi)
      end
   else
      print(k, v)
   end
end
```

which outputs:

```
b   stack
c1  over
c2  flow
a   hello
```

Comment: thank you for the code and the excellent explanation.  Much appreciated.